# select distinct groups in django

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, web-applications

I'm using Django. All my data have a column called 'group' that they belong to. I want to select all the distinct group names from the database. For example, 'groupA', 'groupB', and also get the number of objects that have this group.  For example 'groupA':3.

How can I do this in Django?

I tried the following to get distinct groups.

```
groups = Animal.objects.values('group').distinct()

return render(request, 'group.html', {'groups', groups})
```

but I simply  got the error message `other_dict must be a mapping (dictionary-like) object.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `{'groups', groups}` should become `{'groups': groups}`

To get the list of groups:

```
{% for g in groups %}
   {{g.group}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I get the second key after I pass this into my template?  Namely the list of the group names?

Comment: whatever you put in the values is the one you must call. So you put group, so it is `group`

Comment: But then I will print something like {'group': u'name_1'} {'group': u'name_2'} when I loop over the group I passed to the template.. I just want to print name_1, name_2 when I loop over the group parameter

Comment: Yes! I used this. But I got the above results.

Comment: I see! I'm new to web application. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, do you also know how to count the number of objects each group have and pass it to the template?

Comment: I looked up online and really have no idea how to do that. Could you give me some hint?  I want to combine  group with group_count

Comment: I already give answer on your post problem. What you want is not part of this scope

Comment: @user2649814 As for counting the number of objects in each group, the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/aggregation/#values) gives an example of how to do just that.